# Объединить запросы

Tags: sql, group-by

Есть два запроса, в которых группируются записи по дате.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m-%d-%Y') as date, count(*) as count1
FROM `table`
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m-%d-%Y')

SELECT count(*) as count2, sum(price) as price
FROM `table2`
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m-%d-%Y')
```

В обоих таблицах есть поле date типа `DATETIME`. Можно ли их объединить в один запрос и на выходе получить: date, count1, count2, price

Comment: Есть понимание, что надо делать, если в одном запросе будет дата, которой не будет во втором?

Comment: Да, такое тоже возможно. В таблице table1 всегда больше данных чем в table2

Comment: Т.е. в table2 гарантированно не может быть даты, которой нет в table1 ?

Comment: Да, записи в них пишутся последовательно. Сначала в table1, потом в table2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.date, A.count1, B.count2, B.price
  FROM
   (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m-%d-%Y') as date, count(*) as count1
      FROM `table`
     GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m-%d-%Y')
   ) A
  LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m-%d-%Y') as date,
           count(*) as count2, sum(price) as price
      FROM `table2`
     GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m-%d-%Y')
   ) B
  ON A.date=B.date
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

По логике здесь нужно использовать полное соединение (FULL JOIN). Поскольку его нет в MySQL, то можно [объединить левое и правое](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_full_join_and_mysql.html).

Comment: Т.е. вы предлагаете использовать UNION? Но мне нужно получить дату, количество записей из первой таблицы, количество записей из второй и сумму поля price в качестве столбцов таблицы.

Comment: Я предлагаю эмуляцию FULL JOIN. Отмеченное вами лучшим решение не учитывает случай, когда в правой таблице есть даты, отсутствующие в левой.